# Quiero hacer un existe con el TableAdapter y no me estaria saliendo

Tags: c#, windows-forms, ms-access

Quiero hacer un existe con tableadapter hice una consulta

```
SELECT        Id, Nombre, Apellido, Usuario, Clave
FROM            Usuario
WHERE        (Nombre = ?) AND (Apellido = ?) AND (Usuario = ?)
```

y dentro del codigo

```
  if (this.usuarioTableAdapter.Existe(txtNombre.Text, txtApellido.Text,txtUsuario.Text))
  {
      this.usuarioTableAdapter.CrearUsuario(txtNombre.Text, txtApellido.Text, txtUsuario.Text, txtClave.Text);
      mensaje.Show();
  }
  else
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Ya fue creado un usuario", "Notificacion");
  }
```

No me estaria funcionando

Comment: ¿Existe es una función propia?

Comment: yo al crear el  if (this.usuarioTableAdapter.Existe(txtNombre.Text, txtApellido.Text,txtUsuario.Text)) me dijo no existe el metodo bueno me fui a crearlo y hice esto          internal bool Existe(string text1, string text2, string text3)
        {
            if (text1 !="" && text2 !="" && text3 !="")
            {

                return true;
            }

            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            
            
        } si me podrias dar una mano te agradecería

Comment: Me falta información, esa consulta, ¿En dónde guardas los datos? ¿Por qué quieres realizar una función si solo deseas comprobar que los campos son cadenas vacías? ¿Pueden ser null? mira [ask] para realizar bien la pregunta ya que así noto que me faltan datos